# Adding custom file system support to Apache VFS

Tags: java, apache, vfs

Does Apache VFS provides a pluggable mechanism to add support for a custom file system not provided by default?

Is there any example how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Apache VFS does provide a facility for implementing your own file system providers.  In short, you need to implement your own version of the FileObject, FileSystem, and FileProvider interfaces.

You can find a good example at the following URL.

http://detailfocused.blogspot.com/2009/06/add-plugin-for-apache-vfs.html

Apache also provides a good number of implementations out of the box, so check the source as well.